# What's a good, free source control system for eclipse android development?

Tags: android, version-control, eclipse-plugin

My app code is starting to get unmanageable and I want to start source control, primarily because I need to branch my code.

What are some good systems that you have used in the past and what would you recommend to me.

Requirements:
Must be free
Must integrate with eclipse
Must work well with android development plugin

Comment: @JesperE I'm a lone developer doing hobby programming.  Putting code in VCS isn't typical for my type of work.  This project turned out to be unique.

Comment: I used to think that way, too. Nowadays I'm of the opinion that code not checked in to VCS is as real as code which only exists in your head.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

SVN (Subversion) is very good and there is support for an Eclipse plug-in called [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/).

Comment: My vote goes to Subversion as well. I have tried VSS (which is horible at handling auto generated files like R.java) and CVS (which regularly gave me a lot of issues). Though i dont have much experience in source control tools, Subversion gave me the smoothest ride.

Answer (score 12):

Besides all voting for git I'll vote for the following:

1. If you are willing to use eclipse for android development use SVN or mercurial, because:

   - Both have much better support from eclipse (I belive EGit is still in beta and no public releases are available yet)
   - They are both supported by google code that is excellent source control for open source
   - They both work on all major systems (no offence but git on windows even with MinGW is sometimes creepy)
2. If you are not using eclipse:

   - If you are not using windows for development choose Git because:

     - android uses it
     - it is awesome
   - If you do use windows choose:

     - Git if you are not afraid of console
     - Mercurial otherwise

Answer (score 6):

I vote for **Git**

Comment: Integrates well with Eclipse?

Comment: Exacly: says "no downloads are available yet". BTW see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074941/current-state-of-git-support-in-eclipse

Comment: Seriously, Git is not the **absolute** answer to any VCS question. SVN is pretty good, many users just don't need DVCS and, more important, SVN has better Eclipse support. Things might change but this definitely needs to be taken into account for now. Do you have real feedback about egit (not just a link)?

Comment: @akhnaten: I answered your question
@Pascal: I've tried Git... and honestly, it worked much faster than SVN. Yes Eclipse has better SVN support, but if that's the only consideration, CVS has the best support in Eclipse.

Comment: The Eclipse Platform is slowly but surely moving from CVS to Git. In a year or two, Git will be the primary VCS for Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a project at [code.google.com](http://code.google.com), and use a source code repository provided by them.  I think they offer Subversion and Mercurial as source control systems, and I use Subversion.

After you've got that set up, you can just use [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) to connect to the repository.

Answer (score 2):

Git and SVN are both good choices, although I'd give SVN an edge since it's probably a bit easier to learn if you've never used a source control system before.  As far as Eclipse integration goes, you'd be hard pressed to find a popular source control system that doesn't have an Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Subversion has a simpler (too simple, some would say) view of the entire VCS problem, but the merging model is fundamentally flawed, causing great grief in more advanced merging scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I would also vote for Git. I have little experience with Git and SVN, and I enjoyed Git more. It's fast, it's easy, i didn't have any problems with this. There's good Git repository service github.com, but setting up your own repository is very easy. But you can have some trouble with integrating it with Eclipse :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are not working on a team and you just need version control for yourself, SourceGear Vault is free for a single user and they have a nice Eclipse plug-in.

I use it for Android development and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac, try out Versions. It's a tool for managing SVN repositories and working copies, and it's amazing (No... I don't work for them ;-) )They allow you to create repositories on your own computer, or setup a free one at BeanStalk.com

Comment: Wow, that's amazing >:) And what about the integration with eclipse?

Comment: I don't think there's any integration with Eclipse, unfortunately. Eclipse has it's own SVN plugin that you could probably setup, but I've had pretty bad luck with it. I prefer having a separate app to handle version control, and I just refresh the Eclipse project after Versions updates things.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put in another vote for subversion. It should be easier to learn than git, and will easily provide all you need.

As for the eclipse integration, you can choose between two different plugins: Subclipse or subversive. You can find lots of interesting debates on the net about which is the better one. I'm personally using subversive because it's a bit more intelligent about trunk/branches/tags handling in svn.

Answer (score 0):

Find EGit Releases here : http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/

Since Mar 2010 we did a release every 3 months, current release is 0.10.1
Next release is planned for end of Feb 2011 with Helios SR2.

Answer (score 0):

Subversive plugin for eclipse.