# Another Eclipse/Android/version control system question

Tags: android, version-control, eclipse-plugin

I saw the question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074625/whats-a-good-free-source-control-system-for-eclipse-android-development) and I have a similar but perhaps more detailed question. I have just installed SVN and Subversive and I added an existing project to a repository. Then I checked out the project and opened it. Unfortunately, in Eclipse, the Subversive layout has taken over the Android layout in the Project Explorer view and I'm not too happy about that.

In other words, the Android layout organizes the project under src, gen, assests, res, and other nodes, whereas the Subversive layout organizes the project strictly by the folder structure under the repository. Is there any way to use a source control plug-in AND keep the Android layout? If not, I may just resort to removing the Eclipse version control plug-in and manually use TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having a similar issue with my team.

we thought that having the eclipse plug in would be a great idea (handling everything from the same app) but we got lots of problems with the layout and the conflict resolution.

my advice is to keep editing in eclipse(neat beans or whatever IDE) and use tortoise in your explorer to commit, and when you update hit F5 and continue coding ^^