# How to put an existing Android project on source control using Subversion for Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I have an existing Android project on which I have been working for a while, without using any source control (I know this is dumb).

Finally I have [installed Subclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2074640/113124), but am not sure

- how to move my existing project to SVN using this plugin, and
- where to host it?

Any pointers to this would be helpful. The [Subclipse website](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) is not very descriptive on how this can be done either.

Can someone please outline the steps for me?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Google Code](http://code.google.com) for repository of your project. Other alternatives are [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/) and [gitHub](https://github.com/) (github is if you are using git, which is not your case) and many more. However, all the alternatives I share here are for open sourced projects and so they might not be the best fit for you. In all alternatives you have to register, then create a project (where you specify the license) and finally add your code.

As for how do you check in your project for the first time, I think [this](http://agile.csc.ncsu.edu/SEMaterials/tutorials/subclipse/index.html#section5_0) is good enough description.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to you use open source as pointed by Boris  you can always host it yourself on your server.

Sourcerepo is another alternative and its only $3 approx, suppports svn, mercurial and git.